# Cómo consumir un SOAP WebService con PHP o Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, webservice, soap

Estoy tratando de consumir un SOAP WebService con PHP o AJAX, se supone que mi proveedor de servicio permitió la IP de mi VPS, por lo que el servicio web funciona desde [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html), pero necesito usar los datos en mi página web (que se ejecuta desde mi VPS), así que lo he intentado usando este PHP:

```
<?php
$wsdl = "https://an.url?wsdl";
$options = array(
     'Usuario' => "anUser",
     'Clave' => "aPassword",
     'Rut' => "someData",
     'Dv' => "someMoreData"
);
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($client,true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Pero arroja este error:

[image]

La cosa es que estoy tratando de acceder al método llamado "obtenerReporteFinal" y no sé dónde especificar eso y tal vez ese sea el primer error.

Así que busqué otro método para consumir un SOAP WebService y encontré [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013111/jquery-ajax-consume-soap-web-service) publicación usando ajax. Como tengo una página web hecha en PHP + JavaScript, he intentado con esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<input type="button" id="btnQlo" value="Call Web Service" />


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $(document).on("click","#btnQlo",function(){CallService()});
});


function CallService()
{
    var webServiceURL = 'https://an.url?wsdl';
    var soapMessage = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://another.url/">';
    soapMessage+='<soapenv:Header/>';
        soapMessage+='<soapenv:Body>'
            soapMessage+='<com:obtenerReporteFinal>'
                soapMessage+='<!--Optional:-->'
                    soapMessage+='<arg0>'
                    soapMessage+='<Usuario>anUser</Usuario>'
                    soapMessage+='<Clave>aPassword</Clave>'
                    soapMessage+='<Rut>someData</Rut>'
                    soapMessage+='<Dv>someMoreData</Dv>'
                soapMessage+='</arg0>'
            soapMessage+='</com:obtenerReporteFinal>'
        soapMessage+='</soapenv:Body>'
    soapMessage+='</soapenv:Envelope>';

    $.ajax({
        url: webServiceURL, 
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain : true,
        dataType: "xml", 
        data: soapMessage,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

No sé si ahora estoy llamando correctamente al método "obtenerReporteFinal", pero cuando presiono el botón para llamar al servicio, solo produce este error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si 'http: // localhost' está bloqueado, ¿cómo puede permitírmelo mi proveedor del WebService?

Entonces, ¿cómo puedo hacer que esto funcione en cualquiera de los casos anteriores? Estoy realmente confundido ya que esta es la primera vez que tengo que consumir un servicio web SOAP.

**EDIT**: Contacté a mi proveedor del WebService y me comentó lo siguiente sobre este último error sobre http://localhost bloqueado:

*"Te comento que el error adjunto es porque al momento de realizar el llamado sobre su end point de QA  esta con protocolo inseguro http, lo cual no corresponde por definición y políticas internacionales de nuestra empresa."*

Entonces, ¿será que debo implementar un certificado SSL en mi VPS para que esto funcione? Sé que eso ya sería casi un tema aparte pero si me pueden sugerir alguna guía para hacer eso, estaría agradecido. He probado varias googleando pero no me resulta.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404133/5215609

Comment: @DiegoAvila acabod e probar la respuesta aceptada de ese post y me arroja el mismo error.

Comment: Respuesta rápida: no puedes hacerlo y no tiene solución a no ser que cambien el servidor para que devuelva las cabeceras [CORS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercambio_de_recursos_de_origen_cruzado) que permitan hacer esas consultas desde páginas remotas.

Comment: @OscarGarcia entonces si conociera esas cabeceras CORS sería posible hacer uso del WebService?

Comment: Si las conocieras no, si el servidor las entregara, indicando al navegador que tu página tiene permiso para acceder al api. Es problema del servidor SOAP, no de tu cliente javascript.

Comment: @OscarGarcia a qué te refieres con "entregar" las cabeceras CORS? Es que luego dices "indicando al navegador que tu página tiene permiso" entonces esto último suena como que deben "editar" algún parámetro para otorgarle permisos a mi página. Quiero llamar al proveedor del webService para explicarle esto, por eso necesito tenerlo bien claro yo primero.

Comment: El servidor que sirve el API es el encargado de entregar una serie de cabeceras HTTP que indican al navegador si un sitio externo puede o no acceder a dicho API. Esa URL no entrega dichas cabeceras, por eso tu código javascript provoca ese mensaje. PD: copia/pega los mensajes en texto en tu pregunta, las capturas de pantalla a veces representan un problema en la aplicación móvil de stackoverflow.